# How to learn what is the "key" in Android Studio Bundle?

Tags: java, android, android-intent, bundle, parcelable

I'm using a library which is not up to date. (https://github.com/notsukamto/GFIPhotoPicker)
It has a onActivityResult function to get activity result. It returns an intent with this function

```
    if (selection != null) {
        intent.putExtra(EXTRA_SELECTION, new LinkedList<>(selection));
    }

    public static List<Uri> getSelection(Intent data) {
    return data.getParcelableArrayListExtra(EXTRA_SELECTION);}
```

So my question is what is the key for this Parcelable and how I get that intent correctly?
(I tried "EXTRA_SELECTION" which is not working)

```
Bundle[
  {com.github.potatodealer.gfiphotopicker.activity.extra.SELECTION=
       [file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190114_072919.jpg, 
       file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190114_072904.jpg,       
       file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Camera/IMG_20190114_072848.jpg], 

com.github.potatodealer.gfiphotopicker.activity.extra.FACEBOOK_SELECTION=[],

com.github.potatodealer.gfiphotopicker.activity.extra.INSTAGRAM_SELECTION=[]
    }

]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you access [this directory](https://github.com/notsukamto/GFIPhotoPicker/tree/master/gfiphotopicker/src/main/java/com/github/potatodealer/gfiphotopicker/activity) in the github link you provided, there will be a `EXTRA_SELECTION` constant in each of those activities.

For example, if we click on the `FacebookPreviewActivity.java`, we see:

`private static final String EXTRA_SELECTION = FacebookPreviewActivity.class.getPackage().getName() + ".extra.SELECTION";`

Comment: I tried to change the private state to public and import it to my activity and tried to use it as a key, but it still returns null.